# JavaScript function fires twice on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am building a web app at the moment, and I have a strange problem, I have the following HTML,

It has code that is similar to this format:

```
<article class="item">  
    <header class="active">  
    </header>   
    <div class="item_content">  
       <div class="item-tabs">  
            <ul>  
                <li><a href="#" class="tab-link">Description</a><li>   
                <li><a href="#" class="tab-link">Tasks</a></li> <!-- THERE IS A CLICK EVENT ON THIS -->
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content item-description">Description</div>  
            <div class="tab-content item-tasks">Tasks</div>  
       </div>  
      <article class="item">  
         <header class="active">  
         </header>   
        <div class="item_content">  
            <div class="item-tabs">  
                <ul>  
                    <li><a href="#" class="tab-link">Description</a><li>   
                    <li><a href="#" class="tab-link">Tasks</a></li> <!-- THERE IS A CLICK EVENT ON THIS -->
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content item-description">Description</div>  
                <div class="tab-content item-tasks">Tasks</div>  
            </div>  
        </div>
      </article>  
</article>
```

The first `class="tab-link"` triggers the JavaScript below once, but the second `class="tab-link" triggers the JavaScript below twice. Is there any reason for this?

```
itemTab: function(e) {
    var clicked = $(e.currentTarget),
        clickedTab = clicked.data("tab");

    if(clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find("." + clickedTab).css("display") == "block")
    {           
        clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").slideUp(500, function(){
            clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").removeClass("active");    
        });

        clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".close").css("visibility", "hidden");

        clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
    }
    else
    {
        clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content.active").removeClass("active");
        clicked.parent().addClass("active");
        clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find("." + clickedTab).addClass("active");
        clicked.closest(".item-tabs").find(".close").css("visibility", "visible");
    }

    

    e.preventDefault();

    //stop();
},
```

Comment: how is the click handler registered

Comment: How are you binding your `click` handler?

Comment: just check if the script might me included twice...same thing happened with me..

Comment: Create a fiddle to make things easier for us.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I register the click handler in the backbone view events object like this, `"click .tab-link": "itemTab"`

Comment: There are markup errors in your html.